# How can I make my QGIS Python script work on a Windows environment?

Tags: python, windows, console, qgis, pyqgis

Running a script from the Python console of QGIS on a Windows environment

I am running a script from the Python console of QGIS on a Linux environment that works fine.
I want to share it with colleagues who work on a Windows environment. I already sent it to them and it either works partially or not at all. When it does not work at all it seems it is because QgsProcessing is not able to find the path to the algorithm.

For the moment there is no test on the environment in the script and when I run an algorithm, it looks like that

```
    formula = "(A>-9999999)*{}".format(level)
    alg_params = {
        'BAND_A': 1,
        'FORMULA': formula,
        'INPUT_A': rlayer,
        'RTYPE': 5,
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['RasterCalculator'] = processing.run('gdal:rastercalculator', alg_params)
```

Do I have to set the environment differently for the script to run on windows?

How can I tell the script where to find the algorithm?

I have looked through the documentation but I am not a programmer and I am stuck.